# Localhost is not working in Visual studio web developer 2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis, web

i am having problem with my visual studio 2010 web developer , when every time i run my aplication my localhost is not working i dont event use IIS for my project just a localhost and page not found i have tried to configure my internet properties and checked USE a proxy server for the connection , but still my localhost does'nt work , is there any other way to fix my problem , please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following line to your C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts :
**127.0.0.1 localhost**

Ps: to edit **hosts**, copy it to your desktop, add the line : **127.0.0.1  localhost** , save , copy the new **host** to your folder C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\ then replace the old one

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be **in another application you are running**.
Visual studio uses the same ports/localhosts **like steam and other applicitions**.
To clear this, make sure the program you think is causing the problem doesnt start automaticly start when your PC starts and then restart your pc.

if that isn't the problem you schould look at your localhost itself by typing 127.0.0.1 in your browser to see if it works